# Can't make timezone datetime object to print the right time

Tags: python, django, timezone

I really have trouble grasping this with timezones. I have a calendar app with a model like this:

```
class Events(models.Model):
    dtstart = models.DateTimeField('Start')
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        aware = self.dtstart.replace(tzinfo=timezone.get_current_timezone())
        #dt = defaultfilters.date(aware, 'Y-m-d H')
        dt = aware.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        return dt
```

and the settings.py contains this:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Stockholm'
USE_TZ = True
```

If I use the Django admin interface to add an event that starts about 19:00 tomorrow, the sqlite-db will contain this:

```
$ sqlite3 ~/django_test.db "SELECT dtstart from events_events"
2013-03-04 18:00:00
```

Which seems like a utc timestamp to me (I suspect this is correct). When I render the html it's all good using `{{event.dtstart|date:"H.i"}}`. It show 19:00 as it should. But the problem is that the `__unicode__`-method on the Event class returns `2013-03-04 18:00`. I have, as you can see tried to fix this, but I am stuck.  Where is my problem and how do I make this `__unicode__` method return `2013-03-04 19:00` instead. I think it is daylight saving right now here in Sweden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `.replace(tzinfo=tz)` to set a timezone, use `tz.localize()` instead:

```
aware = timezone.get_current_timezone().localize(self.dtstart)
```

See the [`pytz` documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/):

> The first is to use the localize() method provided by the pytz library. This is used to localize a naive datetime (datetime with no timezone information):
>
> ```
> >>> loc_dt = eastern.localize(datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0))
> >>> print(loc_dt.strftime(fmt))
> 2002-10-27 06:00:00 EST-0500
> ```

However, if your datetimes are UTC times, you should use the UTC timezone instead, then express the time in a different timezone for display:

```
from pytz import UTC

aware = UTC.localize(timezone.get_current_timezone())
dt = aware.astimezone(timezone.get_current_timezone()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```